# Removing items in a container

Tags: java, eclipse, components, containers

When I try to remove Components from a Container, I use this code.

```
private static void clear(){
    for (int i = con.getComponentCount() - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        con.remove(i);
    }
}
```

When I call this function, the function acts as if it has done nothing, but crashes it as if its overloading. It gives no error. But when I put `con.getComponent(i).setVisible(false);` in the code it works, but I want to REMOVE the components. Halp?

Comment: I am assuming this function is in a class, and that con is a member variable of that class? Can you include the line that declares and instantiates that variable? Also, when it crashes, there is no error?

Comment: @NathanielFord: it's probably a  `java.awt.Container` instance.

Comment: I hope that isn't really a mutable static. (Are you multithreading that? And why don't you want to remove component 0?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you are done removing the components you want to remove, call Container.validate(); Container.repaint(); Actually, you might want to revalidate more than that.

Comment: So is the problem resolved? If so, you should mark the best solution as correct. This will close the issue

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
while (con.getComponentCount()>0) {
    con.remove(0);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach better, in general. However, how could the above trigger an IOOBE?

Comment: @pst: right. didn't notice before `i` variable was decrementing on the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried containerObject.repaint() after removing the components?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that con is an awt Container, you can call

```
con.removeAll();
```

that removes all contained components at once.